# Python f-string parsing NoneType from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nonetype, f-string

```
d = {'surname':"Doe",'name':"Jane",'prefix':"Dr."}
f"""{d['prefix'] or ''} {d['name'][0]+'. ' or ''}{d['surname']}"""
```

works, however

```
d = {'surname':"Doe",'name':None,'prefix':"Dr."}
f"""{d['prefix'] or ''} {d['name'][0]+'. ' or ''}{d['surname']}"""
```

does not of course. How can I parse values from a dictionary conditionally? Or are there other work-arounds? I am iterating through a list of dictionaries with a lot of entries each so editing the data beforehand is not really an option here.

Comment: You can use a ternary operator

Comment: I would prefer `d.get('prefix', '')`, as `d['prefix']` will not simply produce a false value if `prefix` isn't a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a condition inside f string

```
f"""{d['prefix'] or ''} {d['surname'][0]+'. ' if d['surname'] is not None else ''}{d['name']}"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Use condition to check if `name` has value.

```
f"""{d['name'][0] if d.get('name') else None}"""
```

Answer (score 0):

use `if` in f-string

```
f"{d['prefix'] or ''} {d['name'] if d['name'] != None else ''}. {d['surname']}"
```